# Ruby on Rails one controller for two features

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `movies_controller.rb` with

```
def index
  respond_with current_user.movies
end
```

This allows me to only show the movies that respond with the current user on the frontpage.

But now I'm also trying to create a feature that shows all recent added movies like this,

```
def index
  respond_with Movies.all
end
```

Can I combine these two definitions in the same controller or do I need to create another controller? Something like `recent_added_movies_controller.rb` and try to seperate the features?

Also I want to show both results on the same page. The `recently added movies` (which shows all added movies) feature is a popup that can be viewed on the frontpage (which shows the movies added by the user).

I've created a codepen that might give a bit more insight in the problem http://codepen.io/alucardu/pen/WQOyPb

Also I'm using AngluarJS to show the results

```
.movie_container{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies | orderBy:'release_date'"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define this in two way like:

```
def index
  if current_user
    respond_with current_user.movies
  else
    respond_with Movies.all
  end
end
```

OR

If you want to list all recent movies for login user as well then you can define a separate action in the same controller like:

```
def recent
  respond_with Movies.all
end
```

Comment: IMO this is one of those places where a ternary makes sense, e.g., `respond_with current_user ? current_user.movies : Movies.all` or even just `respond_with current_user.andand.movies || Movies.all`

Comment: I agree with first statement but not sure about second one.

Comment: I'm stil learning a lot about Rails, so could you explain me how I would display the results from the `recent` definition? Because I want to show both results on the same page (the frontpage). The `recently added movies` feature is a pop up that can be viewed on the frontpage (which shows the movies added by the user).

Comment: I am not completely understood your problem?

Comment: I've created a codepen example of how my layout looks like, might give a bit more insight. http://codepen.io/alucardu/pen/WQOyPb I want to display both results, all the movies, and only the movies added by the user on the same page.

Comment: you need json response or html?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS to list the results on the elements, so I would need a JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

You will use one controller, and possibly multiple actions.

If you show both recent movies, and the user's movies on the same page, you can store any extra information in a class instance variable. When the view is executed, Rails copies all the class instance variables from the controller to the view.

```
@recent_movies = Movies.order("created_at DESC").limit(20)
respond_with current_user.movies
```

You can access `@recent_movies` in your view.

If you show them on different pages, you can make multiple actions:

```
def index
    respond_with current_user.movies
end

def recent
    Movies.order("created_at DESC").limit(20)
end
```

Alternatively, you can use a query parameter:

```
def index
    respond_with (params[:list] == "recent" ? Movies.all : current_user.movies)
end
```

This way, a url which ends in `?list=recent` will show recent movies.

In case you want to show both lists on the same page, get your view to include the same partial twice, and pass it recent movies as a local variable in one, and the user's movies as the same local variable for the other.

Answer (score 0):

They will be two separate `actions` in the same controller, that is. Less code is better and your controller should mirror (as much as possible) your resources. Since you are working with movies `MovieController` is perfect name.

In case you want to combine two responses into one you can do

```
def index
  all_movies   = Movies.all
  users_movies = all_movies.select { |movie| movie.user_id == current_user.id }
  respond_with { user_movies: users_movies, all_movies: all_movies   }
end
```

Comment: Yeah code is DRY but running two database query at the same time is not a great Idea, I think :)

Comment: true, you can do `Movies.all` than filter out user's